# How to hide an unbreakable tag in an unbreakble item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to make an unbreakable item, but is there a way to make it so that nobody can know that it's unbreakable?

Answer (score 3):

As  shown on [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Display_Properties), you simply set `HideFlags` to `4` on the NBT tag. This wasn't too easy to find. Thank you to ExpertCoder14 for finding the correct wiki page.

Example:
`/give Dinnerbone minecraft:diamond_sword{HideFlags:4,Unbreakable:1b}`

This will only hide the unbreakable tag.

Here is a cheat sheet:

| Tooltip Section | HideFlags Value |
| --- | --- |
| Enchantments | 1 |
| Modifiers (e.g. Attack Damage) | 2 |
| Unbreakable | 4 |
| Can Destroy | 8 |
| Can Place | 16 |
| Additional | 32 |
| Dye | 64 |
| All (the sum) | 127 |

2023 update (I finally understand how this works): you can combine these flags by adding them together. For example, to hide Enchantments and Modifiers, you'd put 3. Note: you can also use bitwise OR but addition achieves the same thing in this case. It's simply easier!

Comment: *"This is not well documented"* I beg to differ, the Minecraft Wiki displays this info clearly on the item format page.

Comment: You are right about that. I was just looking in the wrong places.