# How to hide the "NBT : x tag(s)"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

[image: This is what is want to hide.]

The "minecraft:diamond_sword" and "NBT : 2 tag(s)" seems to be unhidable but I've seen many servers with this hidden. So how do you hide these?
And if this requires a plugin, which plugin?

Comment: Also this is maybe a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391921/how-to-hide-an-unbreakable-tag-in-an-unbreakble-item though that is specifically for unbreakable.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use `HideFlags` to remove those values.

The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags) has information on this:

> Used to hide flags (the info in the tool tip) such as enchantments,
> CanDestroy, CanPlaceOn, etc.
>
> To hide multiple tags, you need to add the value of the tags you want to hide. For example, if you want to hide the "Enchantments" and the "Attributes modifiers" tags, the value you need to put is 3 (1+2).

Further information from the wiki:

> `{HideFlags:INT}` The value ranges from 1 to 255, representing 255
> combinations or 8 binary digits.
>
> When adding to create a unique value:
>
> Adding 1 hides "Enchantments"
>
> Adding 2 hides "AttributeModifiers"
>
> Adding 4 hides "Unbreakable"
>
> Adding 8 hides "CanDestroy"
>
> Adding 16 hides "CanPlaceOn"
>
> Adding 32 hides other information, including potion effects, shield
> pattern info, "StoredEnchantments", written book "generation" and
> "author", "Explosion", "Fireworks", and map tooltips
>
> Adding 64 hides "Dyed" on leather armors
>
> Adding 128 hides "Upgrade" on armors
>
> In logical form:
>
> `(HideEnchantments) | (HideAttributeModifiers << 1) | (HideUnbreakable << 2) | (HideCanDestroy << 3) | (HideCanPlaceOn << 4) | (HideOthers << 5) | (HideDyed << 6) | (HideUpgrade << 7)`

I also found a video tutorial:

An example command to hide enchantments may look something like:

```
give @p iron_sword 1 0 {HideFlags:1|ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}
```

1.20.2+ Command for giving a diamond sword with fortune and knockback enchantments hidden (generated using [this generator](https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator)):

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:knockback,lvl:2}],HideFlags:1} 1
```

Comment: I tried  that. Set it to max value. It still shows.

Comment: Also thats like 1.8 where the minecraft:sword thing wasnt even there I suppose and that command doesnt even work in the newer versions.

Comment: @Duomax_ didn't realize the age of the video... maybe see [this?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/aan6vw/hiding_item_tags/) Example: `/give @p minecraft:item{HideFlags:#}` Or, using [this generator](https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator) for 1.20.2+: `/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:knockback,lvl:2}],HideFlags:1} 1` (see edit)